How can I reuse a custom hook?
I am building a roster management application. I have built a roster viewer which uses the useRosterViewer hook.
The source code is something like:
let reducer = (state, action) => {
    let result = { ...state };
    switch (action.type) {
        case "init":
            result.roster = action.roster;
            result.isLoading = false;
            break;
        ........... 
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
export function useRosterViewer() {
    const [itemList, updateItemList] = useReducer(reducer, {
        error: null,
        isLoading: true,
        roster: null,
        ............
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        let getData = async () => {
            let now = new Date();
            let rosterYear = now.getFullYear();
            let rosterMonth = now.getMonth();
            let roster = await Roster(rosterYear, rosterMonth + 1);
            updateItemList({
                roster,
                systemParam,
                type: "init"
            }); 
        }
        getData();
    },[]);
    return {
        error: itemList.error,
        isLoading: itemList.isLoading,
        roster: itemList.roster,
        .............
    }
}

I am going to build a roster editor.
When I am building another hook such as useRosterEditor, the source code is something like:
export function useRosterEditor(){
    const { error, isLoading, roster } = useRosterViewer();
    const [itemList, updateItemList] = useReducer(reducer, {
        error,
        isLoading,
        roster,
    });
    return {
        error: itemList.error,
        isLoading: itemList.isLoading,
        roster: itemList.roster,     
    }
}

The following component uses the useRosterEditor:
export default function RosterEditor(){
    console.log(useRosterEditor());
} 

If I modify the useRosterEditor as below:
export function useRosterEditor(){

    const [itemList, updateItemList] = useReducer(reducer, {
        error:null,
        isLoading:true,
        roster:null,
    });
    useEffect(()=>{
        let getData = async () => {
               const { error, isLoading, roster } = useRosterViewer();
         }
         getData();
        },[]) 
    return {
        error: itemList.error,
        isLoading: itemList.isLoading,
        roster: itemList.roster,     
    }
}

The react prompt the following error:
React Hook "useRosterViewer" is called in function "getData" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"
I use the useRosterViewer hook to fetch roster data for display. It works fine in the roster viewing component. In the RosterEditor component, I need to fetch the roster and other data, so I don't want to duplicate the data-fetching code (i.e. all operations in the getData function of the useRosterViewer hook). Therefore, I want to know
how to reuse the useRosterViewer hook in the RosterEditor component.

What is "the useRosterEditor consumption component" and what exactly is it "reporting"? Please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to do overall here and provide more complete details regarding the problem. Maybe also include a more complete [mcve] if necessary.

Well that sure clears it all up. useRosterEditor is a React hook, so it can call useRosterViewer and useReducer like it already is. This probably isn't exactly the question you are meaning to ask though. What is the issue or problem? What specifically do you need help with? Is something not working as expected?

Hi @TheKNVB I am not quite clear with this part "So, how can I reuse the useRosterViewer hook?" ? It seems you are asking two questions? is it the error or the aforementioned statement in bold - You want help with?

The useEffect hook callback isn't a React component nor React hook, so useRosterViewer and any other React hook cannot be called there. It's still unclear what you are trying to do and seem to be asking XY Problem-type quesitons.

I use the useRosterViewer hook to fetch roster data for display. It works fine in the roster viewing component. In the RosterEditor component, I need to fetch the roster and other data, so I don't want to duplicate the data-fetching code.

I don't' follow at all. What data fetching would you be duplicating? Your post keeps getting more ambiguous. Why can't you just explain the actual problem you are trying to solve?

@TheKNVB You seem to have an interesting problem, but I am afraid I can't understand it. Why not follow this pattern: 1.. I tried this but got duplicates 2. I need this function to fetch data but it doesn't. 3. How can I make the function reusable

What was the issue with the first implementation of useRosterEditor where you call both the hooks like normal? That's the version of the code that is correct with regards to calling React hooks like you are asking about.

Hooks in general, cannot be called outside of a react component. Also react official document states that you cannot call hooks inside a regular js function or if statements. You can find more info here: Rules of Hooks
You can modify the useRosterEditor as below:
    export function useRosterEditor(){

    const [itemList, updateItemList] = useReducer(reducer, {
        error:null,
        isLoading:true,
        roster:null,
    });
    const { error, isLoading, roster } = useRosterViewer();
    return {
        error: itemList.error,
        isLoading: itemList.isLoading,
        roster: itemList.roster,     
    }
}

